# Java: Convert uppercase to lowercase and vice versa without using functions

Tags: java, string

So, our teacher  gave us a challenge in Java with the following conditions:

- User input of a 4 characters string (letters, symbols, and numbers, all mixed)
- If the letter is uppercase then convert it to lowercase, and vice versa.
- Symbols and numbers stay the same.
- Print out the result.

But the restriction is you can't use the functions `split()`, `length()`, and `toUpperCase()`.

My first thought was using `switch` and cases for EVERY letter, but I was wondering if there's a better (read shorter and smarter) alternative:

```
public class program {           
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text;

        System.out.println("Type in:");
        text = input.nextLine();

        switch(text){
            case "A":
                System.out.println("a");
                break;
            case "b":
                System.out.println("B");
                break;

        }
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  StackOverflow works best if you post what you have done so far. Questions that look like "please write my code for me" (even if you didn't intend it that way) generally get downvoted and put on hold as off-topic.  If you show what you've tried and explain what isn't working (include stack trace and/or error messages where appropriate) you are ***much*** more likely to get help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Convert lower to upper case without using toUppercase()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259250/java-convert-lower-to-upper-case-without-using-touppercase)

Comment: What would you not get to use length?!

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a better way. First you need to check if it's a letter in upper or lower case by doing this:

```
char c;
if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {   
    c = c - 32
} else if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {   
    c = c + 32
}
```

as the ASCII value of 'A' is 65, 'B' is 66 and so on, and the ASCII value of 'a' is 97 and so on. You need to change the ASCII values of each alphabet. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is the way to do it, refer to the ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Yeah! right! Thanks matt!!

Comment: you need to use if-else in the above code.

Comment: yeah! Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Thanks in advance, this is what I did`Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce your text:");
        String text;
        text = input.nextLine();

    
        char c = text.charAt(0);
    
        if(c>= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            
            c=(char) (c-32);
            System.out.println(c);
        
        }       
        
        else if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {   
            
            c = (char) (c + 32);
            System.out.println(c);
        
                }
        }` But it only returns the first letter, why?

Comment: you need to loop through all the elements of the string text. As you did text.charAt(0) so you got character at zero. you need to call charAt function in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can just loop the String, then check with this condition:

```
// c => ith letter in String

if(c >='a' && c<='z') c = c-'a' + 'A';
else if(c>='A' && c<='Z') c = c-'A' + 'a';

// append c into new String
```